# Use ConstraintLayout for responsive views

Tags: android, user-interface, android-constraintlayout, constraint-layout-chains

I want to use Constraint Layout to design a layout with automatically wraps in smaller displays, **without using code behind**, see attached example image, please:

[image]

It's something like web grid systems, like **Bootstrap** or **Flex**

Comment: [Google has an open source Flexbox layout](https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout).

Comment: @adneal Great, please post this as answer!

Answer (score -1):

The solution is described in the [Supporting Different Screen Sizes](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html) document available in the standard android documentation.